# Remove duplicates in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries in python and I would like to override old value with duplicate value. Please let me know how can I do.

```
{'message': [{'name': 'raghav', 'id': 10}, {'name': 'raghav', 'id': 11}]}
```

Output should be:

```
{'message': [ {'name': 'raghav', 'id': 11}]}
```

Comment: So, what have you tried to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
d = {'message': [{'name': 'raghav', 'id': 10}, {'name': 'raghav', 'id': 11}]}
#loop over outer dictionary
for key, value in d.items():
    d[key] = [dict([t for k in value for t in k.items()])]
    print(d)
```

### Edit:

As per your requirement:

```
d = {'message': [ {'name': 'raghav', 'id': 11}, {'name': 'krish', 'id': 20}, {'name': 'anu', 'id': 30}]}
for key, value in d.items():
    print [dict((k1,v1)) for k1,v1 in dict([tuple(i.items()) for i in value for val in i.items()]).items()]
```

Comment: i got this error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: can you just share the steps.. It is a `TypeError` which mean you have made a mistake in syntax

Comment: >>> d = {'message': [{'name': 'raghav', 'id': 10}, {'name': 'raghav', 'id': 11}]}
>>> for key, value in d.items():
...   d[key] = [dict([t for k in value for t in k.items()])]
...   print d

Comment: Hey, unfortunately it is running perfectly fine in my system. I am using `Ubuntu 16.0` and `ipython` with `python 2.7`.

Comment: Just check https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_interpreter by copy paste my code module. I just check there and it is running perfectly fine.

Comment: Hi,
Running fine for me. But it is not working as expected. Can you see this.
i have this input.

d = {'message': [{'name': 'raghav', 'id': 10}, {'name': 'raghav', 'id': 11}, {'name': 'krish', 'id': 20}, {'name': 'anu', 'id': 30}]}

but my output should be 

d = {'message': [ {'name': 'raghav', 'id': 11}, {'name': 'krish', 'id': 20}, {'name': 'anu', 'id': 30}]}

remove old value and replace with new value and i need all the values along with new duplicate value.

Comment: You the guy.. It's works for me. Thank you for your quick help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by "override old value with duplicate value". If you mean just picking the second `dict` from the list, you could:

```
print({k: [v[1]] for (k, v) in data.items()})
```

If the idea is to update the "name" with a newer value of "id" as you move along the list, then maybe:

```
def merge_records(data):
    records = data['message']
    users = {}
    for record in records:
        name = record['name']
        id_ = record['id']
        users[name] = id_
    new_records = []
    for name, id_ in users.items():
        new_records.append({'name': name, 'id': id_})
    return {'message': new_records}
```

*But*, if you have any control over how the data is represented, you might reconsider. You probably want a different data structure.

Comment: Hi,
This works. But i have some other values too. i need those values also.

{'message': [{'name': 'raghav', 'id': 10}, {'name': 'raghav', 'id': 11}, {'name': 'krish', 'id': 20}, {'name': 'anu', 'id': 30}]}

with the given script i got only duplicate value. i need all the values along with latest duplicate value.

Comment: we might not have the same definition of "duplicate". Do you mean if a different value for a key appears later in the list, use that instead? And collapse it all down to one `dict`?

Comment: yes. i need to check dictonires which have duplicate value say ex name:raghav when any values comes with same name override old value in the list of dictionries.

Comment: Hi,

It should not be like reassigning values. i  might have 50 values in one dictionary.  when any dictionary comes with same name "raghav" just override with new dictionary. i cannot reassign for all values in dictionary for all duplicates. it is like removing first occurrence duplicate value.